# Unrecognized variable in .cmake file

Tags: cmake

I give the following example to illustrate my problem:

CMakeLists.txt

```
....
option(MY_TEST_VARIABLE "test" OFF)
include(my.cmake)
...
```

my.cmake

```
if(MY_TEST_VARIABLE)
  message("MY_TEST_VARIABLE is ON")
else()
  message("MY_TEST_VARIABLE is OFF")
end()
```

As you can see  CMakeLists.txt will invoke my.cmake, and both files share the same variable `MY_TEST_VARIABLE`. In CMakeLists.txt, `MY_TEST_VARIABLE`is set,but it cannot be recognized in my.cmake. So when run cmake, the following message is given:

`MY_TEST_VARIABLE is ON`

So my question is how we can make the variable `MY_TEST_VARIABLE` visible for both files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MY_TEST_VARIABLE` should be visible in both files and it probably is.

This problem can happen if you executed cmake the first time with `option(MY_TEST_VARIABLE "test" ON)` or manually modified CMakeCache.txt in your build directory.

If CMakeCache.txt already contain an option `MY_TEST_VARIABLE` with a value. It will override your call `option(MY_TEST_VARIABLE "test" OFF)` (which is an expected behavior as the `option` command provides a default value if the user did not select a value).

Check that your variable is not already set to `ON` in CMakeCache.txt (via cmake-gui or a text editor). If your project does not include other options (or if you want to only use the default values) you can even remove CMakeCache.txt to be sure to use the default value for your option.